# SVG circle animation issue

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

The `<circle />` is formed but it doesn't move with the `@keyframes`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.div1 {
  animation: viji 3s 2;
}

@keyframes viji {
  0% {top: 30px; right: 150px}
  25% {top: 130px; right: 150px}
  40% {top: 230px; right: 150px}
  75% {top: 330px; right: 150px}
}
```

```html
<svg class="div1" height="100px">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `.div1`'s `position` to anything other than the *default value* of `static`, in order to apply the `top` and `right` *properties*:

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute; /* or "relative" / "fixed" */
  animation: viji 3s 2;
}

@keyframes viji {
  0% {top: 30px; right: 150px}
  25% {top: 130px; right: 150px}
  40% {top: 230px; right: 150px}
  75% {top: 330px; right: 150px}
}
```

```html
<svg class="div1" height="100px">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do use Position for some animation effect

```css
circle {
  cx: 50;
  cy: 50;
  r: 50;
  fill: red;
}

.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  animation: viji 3s 2;
}

@keyframes viji {
  0% {top: 30px;right: 150px;}
  25% {top: 130px;right: 150px;}
  40% {top: 230px;right: 150px;}
  75% {top: 330px;right: 150px;}
}
```

```html
<svg class="div1" height="100px">
  <circle/>
</svg>
```